# Как я могу создать что-то вроде роутинга на websocket клиенте в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, веб-программирование, websocket

я раньше писал на js и всё было очень просто. У меня была функция onmessage, там я получал data, парсил ее и из нее доставал поле route. Потом это и был по сути роут. Вот так примерно.

```
const routes = {
  'route_1': () => {},
  'route_2': () => {}
}
...
ws.onmessage = (d) => {
 const data = JSON.Parse(d);
 if(routes[data.route]
   routes[data.route](data.data)
}
```

И это прекрасно работало в JS. Но как быть в C#?
Я могу точно так же парсить json. Но я вот это не совсем понимаю.
Там же надо создать класс, который описывает приходящие данные. Вроде такого:

```
class Data{
  public string route;
  public string data;
}
ws.onmessage = (d) => {
  var data = JSON.Parse<Data>();
}
```

Но мне же постоянно разные по структуре данные будут приходить. Для того чтоб знать какие надо сначала распарсить и посмотреть поле route. Как это обычно принято делать? Не могу найти.

Answer (score 1):

> Но мне же постоянно разные по структуре данные будут приходить.

Ну и для каждого типа ты в любом пишешь код, на любом языке. Да, структуру на `JS` не описываешь, но обработчики приходится.

---

Что касается `Websocket`, `Unity3D` тут роли не играет, чисто `C#`.

---

Некоторые инструменты `C#` отсутствуют, вместо них в `Unity3D` есть [JsonUtility](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.html). Не обязательно использовать `class`, можно `struct`.

```
[Serializable]
public struct TileLocation
{
    public Vector2Int position;
    public Vector2Int vector;
}
```

---

```
string json; // "{ "position" : { "x": 2, "y": 3 }, "vector": { "x": 1, "y": 0 } }"
TileLocation location = JsonUtility.FromJson<TileLocation>(json);
```

---

```
TileLocation location = new TileLocation()
{
    position = new Vector2Int(2, 3),
    vector = Vector2Int.right
};
string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(location);
```

---

Объект не обязательно должен полностью соответствовать `json`, это не приводит к ошибкам, излишние данные игнорируются, недостающим ничего не присваивается. То есть один `json` можно даже делить на несколько моделей данных.

---

Так-же есть различные решения в [Unity Asset Store](https://assetstore.unity.com/?q=json&orderBy=1).

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете библиотеку Newtonsoft.Json, то вам подойдёт следующий класс конверта сообщения (а если вы её не используете, то пора начинать использовать):

```cs
class Message
{
    public string route;
    public JToken data; 
}
```

Также можно использовать в качестве конверта [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm).

После того, как вы определитесь с обработчиком, JToken можно десериализовать в конкретный тип данных:

```cs
interface IRouteHandler
{
    void Handle(JToken data);
}

abstract class RouteHandler<T> : IRouteHandler
{
    protected abstract void Handle(T data);

    void IRouteHandler.Handle(JToken data)
    {
        this.Handle(data.ToObject<T>());
    }
}

// Пример конкретного обработчика
class FooHandler : RouteHandler<Foo>
{
    protected override void Handle(T data)
    {
        // …
    }
}
```

Если вам ближе не ООП, а делегаты - вот так можно "замкнуть" конкретный тип в делегате:

```cs
delegate void RouteHandler(JToken data);
delegate void RouteHandler<T>(T data);

static class Route
{
    public RouteHandler For<T>(RouteHandler<T> handler)
        => data => handler(data.ToObject<T>());
}

// …

Dictionary<string, RouteHandler> routes = new
{
    { "foo", Route.For<Foo>(() => 
        {
            // …
        }
    )},
    { "bar", Route.For<Bar>(() => 
        {
            // …
        }
    )},
};
```

Наконец, если хочется чего-то совсем примитивного и без лишних сущностей, можно сами классы сообщений сделать одновременно и обработчиками:

```cs
interface IRouteHandler
{
    void Execute();
}
delegate void RouteHandler(JToken data);

static class Route
{
    public RouteHandler For<T>() where T : IRouteHandler
        => data => data.ToObject<T>().Execute();
}

// …

Dictionary<string, RouteHandler> routes = new
{
    { "foo", Route.For<Foo>() },
    { "bar", Route.For<Bar>() },
};
```

---

Отмечу, что более в современной `System.Text.Json` вместо `JToken` для тех же целей нужно использовать тип [`JsonElement`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement?view=net-7.0), а дальнейшая десериализация вместо ToObject делается через [`JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.deserialize?view=net-7.0#system-text-json-jsonserializer-deserialize-1(system-text-json-jsonelement-system-text-json-jsonserializeroptions)). В остальном всё так же.

Comment: `System.Text.Json` недоступен в Unity. А чтобы не творить такие костыли с `JToken`, есть `TypeNameHandling`.

Comment: @aepot TypeNameHandling - это не то. Эта штука позволяет указать любой тип, а надо-то конкретный, подходящий для указанного "маршрута".